# Dummy if the same value occurs on a later date in python (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, loops, date

I have a `df` that contains, among other columns, for each name several consecutive dates (yyyy-mm-dd) on which the name occurred. I want to create a dummy variable in a new column `Rep` that indicates whether the same name appears again on a later date.
I thought about looping through the two columns `Name` and `Date` in such a way that for each name with the youngest date a `0` is set while for all others a `1`.
Additionally, I tried to use `duplicated` but as there are multiple occurences of the same `Name` on the same `Date`, this method does not provide the targeted output.

`df`:

```
Name    Date
A       2006-01-01
B       2006-01-02
A       2006-01-04
A       2006-01-04
B       2006-01-08
```

outcome `df`:

```
Name    Date           Rep
A       2006-01-01     1
B       2006-01-02     1
A       2006-01-04     0
A       2006-01-04     0
B       2006-01-08     0
```

Code with `duplicated` method:

```
df = df(by=["Name", "Date"])
df["Rep"] = df.duplicated(subset=["Name", "Date"], keep = "last")
```

Achieved outcome:

```
Name    Date           Rep
A       2006-01-01     1
B       2006-01-02     1
A       2006-01-04     1 # this should be 0!
A       2006-01-04     0
B       2006-01-08     0
```

As required, a sample of one of the csv files:

```
Name;Date;Name_Parent;Amount_Est
A;2006-01-01;3;646,200.00
B;2006-01-02;2;25,000,000.00
A;2006-01-04;3;18,759,000.00
A;2006-01-04;5;18,759,000.00
C;2006-01-04;4;18,759,000.00
B;2006-01-08;6;945,000.00
C;2006-01-09;2;945,000.00
A;2006-01-10;4;945,000.00
```

To create `df`, i used pandas.
As i have 40 singular csv files, i used a loop:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob2 as glob

# import and merge data
path = r'/Users/...'
all = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

l = []

for f in all:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(f, sep =";", index_col = None, header = 0)
    df1 = df1.drop(df1.index[0])
    l.append(df1)

df = pd.concat(l, axis = 0)
del f, all, df1, l, path
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Upload a sample (not the whole thing) of your dataset (e.g. source/input csv file) and the code you used to create the df from the dataset. Then, I can help you.

Comment: @Joshua, sorry I'm new to SO, so I don't really know what you need. I read that it is not possible to upload files to SO. But I have a csv file that looks like above. After importing it, there was no need for further coding so far.

Comment: you can paste a small chunk / sample of the csv here (in code format). or, you can link to it in an external website like google drive. I mean the code you used to generate the dataframe. Like there are several python libraries for dataframe generation from csv, and the solution might vary depending on which library you used. If possible, include the line where you link to the csv file too, rather than just the name of the library. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes, it helps. I have answered your question below. Let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. Perhaps this will help someone in the future:

In a new df, `df_max`, I extracted from `df` all names with the most recent date since there are no further entries after the respective most recent date (dummy = `0`) . Then, I kept only the relevant columns in `df_max` that will be used for the merger. Next, in a new column `Rep`, I set each value to `0`. After merging the two dfs `df` and `df_max` to `df_new` on the columns `Name` and `Date`, all most recent entries, regardless how often the `Name` and `Date` combination occurs, are filled with `0` on `Rep`. Lastly, I filled the `nan` of `Rep` with `1`.

```
df = df.sort_values(by=["Name", "Date"])

df_max = pd.DataFrame(df.sort_values("Date").groupby("Name").last().reset_index())
df_max = df_max[["Name", "Date"]]
df_max["Rep"] = "0"

df_new = pd.merge(df, df_max, how="left", left_on=["Name", "Date"], right_on = ["Name", "Date"])
df_startups_new = df_startups_new.fillna(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample output:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
from shutil import copyfile
import os
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as fp:
        for i, line in enumerate(fp):
            pass
    return i + 1
def read_nth(fname,intNth):
    with open(fname) as fp:
        for i, line in enumerate(fp):
            if i == (intNth-1):
                return line
def showRepetitions(fname):
    temp8 = []
    temp3 = []
    for temp1 in range(file_len(fname),-1,-1):
        if "Name;Date;Name_Parent;Amount_Est" in read_nth(fname,temp1):
            temp8.append("Name;Date;Name_Parent;Amount_Est;Repeats_X_More_Times\n")
            break
        temp2 = read_nth(fname,temp1)
        temp8.append(temp2.strip()+";"+str(temp3.count(temp2.split(";")[0]))+"\n")
        temp3.append(temp2.split(";")[0])
    f = open(fname, "w")
    for temp9 in reversed(temp8):
        f.write(temp9)
    f.close()
path = r'C:\Users\USERname4\Desktop'
all = glob.glob(path + r"\*.csv")
l = []
for f in all:
    f2 = f[:-3]+"txt"
    copyfile(f, f2)
    showRepetitions(f2)
    df1 = pd.read_csv(f2, sep =";", index_col = None, header = 0)
    os.remove(f2)
    l.append(df1)
df = pd.concat(l, axis = 0)
print(df)
```

Comment: Somehow the concatenation of the csv files no longer works. For `df = pd.concat(l, axis = 0)` I get the error message "ValueError: No objects to concatenate". Of course I have adjusted the file path. Do you know what the reason could be?

Comment: It works for me 100% lol. Maybe it is the filepath slash direction. I use windows so my filepath slash direction is different from your filepath  slash direction. There are 2 lines in which you need to change the slash direction. Ensure you change them both.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, thanks for pointing it out. :) I did not change the slash in the glob.glob line. Unfortunately, I had to stop the execution of the code after 1,5h as my df has a size of 350,000x30. Is there perhaps another, quicker way to achieve the desired output?

Comment: @mcm Ahh you need efficiency, I see. Alas, I specialise in inefficient coding. hahah. but on a serious note, I dont suppose it can be efficient using this pre-processing method. but, I suppose hypothetically you can get a better efficiency if you process it on-the-go in pandas itself. on-the-go processing would be less resource intensive than pre-processing. however, i am not well versed in pandas :(

Comment: That's okay! Anyways, thanks a lot for your help!!